# Security of Video on JSP

Tags: java, media-player, jmf

I am a java developer. I am able to play video on jsp page via JMF(Java Media Framework) and other flash players. Also able to download that video file. Now I want to add some extra security features.

1. A watermark should be visible when video is playing. Is this can be done in media player or need to attach watermark when video is creating. What is the way to achieve this functionality?
2. Once video is downloaded, it should be played only once. After 1st play video should not be played again or be corrupted. How this functionality can be achieved/

If anyone have idea about this security or way of doing this, please drop some light...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Advice: Give up. Once you're showing the user video, a sufficiently motivated user *will* be able to capture that video.

Comment: we are not getting this point can you describe it more

Comment: No matter how many security mesaures you put in, no matter how hard you try, at the end of the day *the user has to be able to watch the video*. And if the user can watch the video, *they can circumvent the security*. This is completely unavoidable whenever you give data to the user; you cannot change this.